# Posterior Given Poisson Prior and Strange Density Function

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, statistical-inference

I'm trying to approach the problem [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500363/expectation-maximization-correctness-of-problem-formulation), but I think the explanation I provided there is probably confusing, so I'm simplifying the problem so someone can hopefully provide some insight.

Suppose I have a Poisson prior, $Z \sim \texttt{Poisson} (\lambda)$, for some known $\lambda$. Now, given this observed density:

$
P(Y_i = x | \lambda) = \begin{cases}
e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x/x! & \text{if $x \neq 3, x \neq 1$} \\
e^{-\lambda}\lambda^1/1! + e^{-\lambda}\lambda^3/3! & \text{if $x = 1$} \\
0 & \text{if $x = 3$} \\
\end{cases}
$

I'm trying to determine (the expectation of) the posterior distribution $P(Z \mid X)$. Is this tractable?